error: Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from "path"
"error: Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from C:\Users\USER\Desktop\picky_anu_anshif\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\UI\LogBoxImages\chevron-right.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:"
When I updated my rn from 0.72.5 to 0.74.2, I received this issue from React Native. The build was completed successfully, but then this problem showed up.
Files:
package.json-
{
  "name": "Picky_Assist",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^11.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.3",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.7.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "Camera",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Microphone",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.74.84",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.84",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.84",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4",
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": {
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
    }
  }
}

metro.config.json-
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};

App.tsx-
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>App</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};

I have deleted node-module and reinstalled
gradlew clean
